# Java SDK10: Is cast explicitly required?

Tags: java

I'm working through a Java book based on JDK 8. In the chapter about inheritance and generalisation the following example is shown:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C1 extends B { public void x1() {System.out.println("C1.x1");} }
class C2 extends B { public void x2() {System.out.println("C2.x2");} }
```

Then, some object variables are declared, all of type `A`:

```
A obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4;
```

These variables are populated with instances of the four classes:

```
obj1 = new A();
obj2 = new B();
obj3 = new C1();
obj4 = new C2();
```

Now, `obj3.x1()` doesn't work because `obj3` is of type `A`, and `x1()` is not defined in `A`. In the book, now one can declare a new variable `obj5` of type `C1` and assign to it the value of `obj3`:

```
C1 obj5 = obj3; // then obj5.x1() should work
```

However on this line I get an `Incompatible Types` compile error.

Is this different between SDK8 and 10? Or am I missing some error somewhere?

As a side note: casting such as in `C1 obj5 = (C1) obj3` works.

Comment: Are you saying that it works with Java 8 ?

Comment: You need to cast. The closest thing that could be different is the var declaration. If you declare it as A, then you have to cast.

Comment: The compiler cant know that an `A` object, which `obj3` is, is also a `C1` object. Thus it is complaining and protecting you from a possible mistake. It is like if you are assuming that an `Animal` is also a `Dog`. But it could also be a `Cat`. However, when you are casting, you are telling the compile *"Hey, it's fine, I know that it really is a `C1`"*.

Comment: You need that cast even on Java 8. Maybe the example was slightly different in the book?

Comment: I'm quite confident I'm reproducing the example as close as possible, that's why I dont understand why I cant run it

Comment: Well, there could be a typo in the book. Can you link to it somehow?  PS: "as close as possible" would be "exactly"

Comment: @TMOTTM Definitely an error in the book.

Comment: @glglgl You mean the second line on of the listing on the second page in the screenshot (`//OK`) is wrong?

Comment: @TMOTTM Right, that's what I meant. That's "nicht erlaubt" as well :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By casting, you tell the compiler that in your opinion, the assignment is ok because you consider `obj3` to be of type `C1`. Then the compiler believes you and proceeds.

If you lied on this, you get a runtime exception. If not, all is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You do need to cast, and there is no difference between Java 8 and Java 10 with regard to this. This is easier to understand if you give the classes meaningful names. Suppose that A = Animal, B = Mammal, C1 = Dog, C2 = Cat:

```
class Animal {}
class Mammal extends Animal {}
class Dog extends Mammal { public void x1() {System.out.println("Woof");}
class Cat extends Mammal { public void x2() {System.out.println("Meow");}

Animal obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4;

obj1 = new Animal();
obj2 = new Mammal();
obj3 = new Dog();
obj4 = new Cat();
```

When you try to do this assignment:

```
Dog obj5 = obj3;  // obj3 is of type Animal
```

the cast is necessary because `obj3` is of type `Animal`, but by looking at this line alone the compiler cannot be sure whether it's actually a `Dog` or something else. You'll have to use a cast to tell the compiler "I know better than you what this is, so I want you to treat this `Animal` as if it's a `Dog`".

Note that a runtime check will still be done - if, at runtime, it turns out that `obj3` refers to an object that is not a `Dog`, you'll get a `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 1):

It’s an error in the book you are quoting. There is no difference between Java 8 and 10 here. Also in Java 8 you need the explicit cast:

```
    C1 obj5 = (C1) obj3;
    // then obj5.x1() works:
    obj5.x1();
```

This has been so since Java 1.0, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following code :

```
A a = new C1(); //reference variable of *A* class points object of *C1* class
C1 c1 = a; //compile time error, requires casting
C1 c1 = (C1) a; // type casting A to C1
```

In the above code, typecasting object of C1 class into A class will throw **ClassCastExcepiton** if a is not an object of the C1 class. If A and C1 class are not related to each other and doesn't part of the same type hierarchy, the cast will throw compile time error e.g. you can not cast String and StringBuffer, as they are not from same type hierarchy.